# How do I see all columns in a geopandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

Here is what I have tried:

```
# load shape file
shpfile = r"...\PycharmProject\maps\CA_Counties\CA_Counties_TIGER2016.shp"
map_df = gpd.read_file(shpfile);
map_df.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
print(map_df.head())
```

But it shows only some columns, similar to a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Although Geopandas extends Pandas, you'll still need to import Pandas in order to use `set_option`. All of your options will then carry over to your Geopandas dataframes.

This modification to your original code should work:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# change the global options that Geopandas inherits from
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)

# load shape file
shpfile = r"...\PycharmProject\maps\CA_Counties\CA_Counties_TIGER2016.shp"
map_df = gpd.read_file(shpfile);
print(map_df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by .info

```
print(map_df.info())
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

max_columns won't work for the geodataframe objects. What you can do is turn the column names into a list:

`print(map_df.columns.tolist())`